# Spark Dataframe Exception

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Lets say i have two dataframes below, these two dataframes to be created via scala code and then jar is to be built.

```
{

  def main(args: Array[String]) 
{
    val df1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,0,1,0)).toDF("col1")
    val df2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(234,43,341,42)).toDF("col2")

}
}
```

My requirement is to create jar and submit a spark submit.

Let's say if the dataframe 1 fails due to some issue spark, submit should exit without continuing to dataframe df2.

How to handle this error to exit in scala object ?

Comment: try and catch exception for df1.

Answer (score 0):

spark job consists of 3 parts

1. Logical plan.
2. Optimization on the Logical Plan such as Column pruning and Predicate Pushdown.
3. The cost function to select the best logical plan and execute it(Physical Plan).

Since we know that everything is lazy by default in scala. All the 3 above processes are done when we are using lazy evaluation. It is not possible to exit out or raise an exception when you are using lazy because the physical entity i.e datatype validation , value existence is still not identified.
However, you can do it when you declare the **val** for Strict Evaluation.

Declaring the val as Strict has consequences

1. All the spark optimization on the logical plan and the physical plan
   are skipped.
2. Every **val** will be evaluated every time when declared leading to
   high in-memory usage which will soon lead to memory spillover.

Comment: thanks for the details given samrat. I am still finding a way to exit the code if there is an error occurs. ,I do not want to continue to next data frame execution after the action is triggered and failed.